# How to get a reference to a class that is instantiated on runtime?

Tags: java

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

I am relatively new to java and I was wondering how to handle a specific scenario.

In brief, imagine i have a Jbutton which has an action event to make a new instance of a class if pressed by the user. How do i go about getting a reference to that newly created instance in order to perform a dot operator method on it.

For example, if i create a "new Car();" as a part of the action event, how do i access that car, or allow another button or another part of the GUI to access that car and perform functions on it.

I am sorry if this has been asked before, however, I cannot find anything. Even if someone could point me in the right direction, I will do the research myself and learn what i need to know.

Comment: by `Car myCar = new Car();` you create the instance of that class. Then you can execute methods of that class like `myCar.drive();` You could store the newly created instance in a data structure or an instance variable of the class your working with, for example. I really recommend completing some Java beginners tutorials. There are tons of them online. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

It definetely seems that you quite are not familiar with OOP concepts. Anyway, here is an answer.

You can define an attribute first, so that it can be accessed by other functions. (Declare this as a class variable.)

```
Car car;
```

Then in the button clicked event, you can initialize the reference by,

```
car = new Car();
```

Then you can do whatever you want with the Car object you've just created.

If you need many car objects, define a collection of Car references as an attribute.

```
List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>(); // for the simplicity, I've initialized the List in a single line.
```

Then in the button click event, simple add a new car object to the list.

```
cars.add(new Car());
```

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense, however what if i wanted to define several car attributes, for example:
Car car, car1, car2;
and then on action event of the button, create firstly the car, then on second click car1 and finally car 2?

Comment: You could, for example, store your car instances in an [array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Comment: Thanks very much. Appreciate the help. I will look into collections.

Comment: @user3830092 : see the edit of my answer.
@user1555863 : If he uses an array, the number of elements would be fixed. That's why I suggested to use a `List`.

Comment: Ah yeah, I understand I would need to declare the amount of arrays before runtime if i were to use array list. The collection example you provided was very useful thanks. I am trying it now :)